# How to apply the table properties to all the results

Tags: php, css

I am pasting my code below............my problem is in the else part th tag properties are not applying so fields width is shrinking. How should we make th tag properties applies in else part also.

Note:The format should be same.

```
<?php 
    $network_name="";
    foreach($channel_summary as $c) {
        $channel_str = "";
        if($network_name!=$c['a']) { 
            $channel_str .= $c['a'].'~'.str_replace('/','surero',$c['b']).'~'.$c['c'].'~'.str_replace(' ','surero',$c['d']).'~'.date('d-M-Y', strtotime( $c['e'])).'~'.date('d-M-Y', strtotime( $c['f'])).'~'.$c['g'].'~'.$c['h'].'~'.str_replace('@','surero',$c['i']).'~'.str_replace(' ','surero',$c['j']).'~'.$c['k'];
?>
<br /><p>Network Name: <?php echo $c['a'];
    $network_name=$c['a'];?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  Network Contact: <?php echo $c['i'] ?> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <!--<input type="Submit" class= "submit" value="Network RO" onclick="javascript:NetworkROPDF(<?php echo $order_id ?>,'<?php echo $network_name;?>')" target="_blank" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-->
    <input type="Submit" class= "submit" value="Network RO PDF" onclick="javascript:NetworkRO(<?php echo $order_id ?>,'<?php echo $network_name;?>')" target="_blank" /></p>
<table><tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>E</th>
    <th>F</th>
    <th> G</th>
    <th> H </th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $c['b']."/".$c['a'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $c['c'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $c['d'] ?></td>
    <td><?php print date('d-M-Y', strtotime( $c['e']))  ?></td>
    <td><?php print date('d-M-Y', strtotime( $c['f']))     ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $c['g']  ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $c['h']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $c['g']* $c['h']?>
    <td><a href=javascript:add_price(<?php echo $order_id ?>,'<?php echo $channel_str;?>')>Add Price</a> </td>
</tr>
</table><?php } else
    {
        $channel_str .= $c['a'].'~'.str_replace('/','surero',$c['b']).'~'.$c['c'].'~'.str_replace(' ','surero',$c['d']).'~'.date('d-M-Y', strtotime( $c['e'])).'~'.date('d-M-Y', strtotime( $c['f'])).'~'.$c['g'].'~'.$c['h'].'~'.str_replace('@','surero',$c['i']).'~'.str_replace(' ','surero',$c['j']).'~'.$c['k'];
?><table>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $c['b']."/".$c['a'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $c['c'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $c['d'] ?></td>
    <td><?php print date('d-M-Y', strtotime( $c['e']))  ?></td>
    <td><?php print date('d-M-Y', strtotime( $c['f']))     ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $c['g']  ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $c['h']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $c['g']* $c['h']?>
    <td><a href=javascript:add_price(<?php echo $order_id ?>,'<?php echo $channel_str;?>')>Add Price</a> </td>
</tr></table>
<?php }}?>
```

Comment: Actually i am displaying results group wise based on network.........my code follow principle like this initially network_name is null when it goes to first loop it save network_name and display first row from result set. In second loop it will compare network_name of that row with previously saved network_name if it equals it goes to else part otherwise it will go to if part. When it goes to else part i am not giving th tags so it's not following th properties. I want else part result also with th tag properties..........

Comment: deepak you can see the image below if u have any doubts........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are using different table for else part. Try this code

```
<?php
 $network_name = "";
?>
<table>
<?php
foreach ($channel_summary as $c) {
    $channel_str = "";
    if ($network_name != $c['a']) {

        $channel_str .= $c['a'] . '~' . str_replace('/', 'surero', $c['b']) . '~' . $c['c'] . '~' . str_replace(' ', 'surero', $c['d']) . '~' . date('d-M-Y', strtotime($c['e'])) . '~' . date('d-M-Y', strtotime($c['f'])) . '~' . $c['g'] . '~' . $c['h'] . '~' . str_replace('@', 'surero', $c['i']) . '~' . str_replace(' ', 'surero', $c['j']) . '~' . $c['k'];
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Network Name: <?php echo $c['a']; $network_name = $c['a']; ?></td>
            <td colspan="3">Network Contact: <?php echo $c['i'] ?></td>            
            <td colspan="3"><input type="Submit" class= "submit" value="Network RO PDF" onclick="javascript:NetworkRO(<?php echo $order_id ?>,'<?php echo $network_name; ?>')" target="_blank" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
            <th>E</th>
            <th>F</th>
            <th>G</th>
            <th>H</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td><?php echo $c['b'] . "/" . $c['a'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $c['c'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $c['d'] ?></td>                          
            <td><?php print date('d-M-Y', strtotime($c['e'])) ?></td>
            <td><?php print date('d-M-Y', strtotime($c['f'])) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $c['g'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $c['h'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $c['g'] * $c['h'] ?>
            <td><a href=javascript:add_price(<?php echo $order_id ?>,'<?php echo $channel_str; ?>')>Add Price</a> </td>
        </tr>


        <?php
    } else {
        $channel_str .= $c['a'] . '~' . str_replace('/', 'surero', $c['b']) . '~' . $c['c'] . '~' . str_replace(' ', 'surero', $c['d']) . '~' . date('d-M-Y', strtotime($c['e'])) . '~' . date('d-M-Y', strtotime($c['f'])) . '~' . $c['g'] . '~' . $c['h'] . '~' . str_replace('@', 'surero', $c['i']) . '~' . str_replace(' ', 'surero', $c['j']) . '~' . $c['k'];
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $c['b'] . "/" . $c['a'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $c['c'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $c['d'] ?></td>                          
                <td><?php print date('d-M-Y', strtotime($c['e'])) ?></td>
                <td><?php print date('d-M-Y', strtotime($c['f'])) ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $c['g'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $c['h'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $c['g'] * $c['h'] ?>
                <td><a href=javascript:add_price(<?php echo $order_id ?>,'<?php echo $channel_str; ?>')>Add Price</a> </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 for making the code readable.  @venkata, when doing a large table or query, try to format like Deepak has shown.  The errors will pop out at you much easier.

Comment: Thanks Deepak.........i tried by placing everything in single table but i didn't get idea to put from the starting onwards single table...........